# Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null when upload image use file system Laravel

Tags: laravel, image-uploading, laravel-filesystem

I want to upload an image using Laravel storage file system in my admin data. However, there's an error when I attempt to upload an image.

> Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null

**Controller**

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $admin              = $request->all();
    $fileName           = $request->file('foto')->getClientOriginalName();
    $destinationPath    = 'images/';
    $proses             = $request->file('foto')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);

    if($request->hasFile('foto'))
    {
        $obj = array (
            'foto'  => $fileName,
            'nama_admin' => $admin['nama_admin'],
            'email' => $admin['email'],
            'jabatan' => $admin['jabatan'],
            'password' => $admin['password'],
            'confirm_password' => $admin['confirm_password']
        );
        DB::table('admins')->insert($obj);
    }
    return redirect()->route('admin-index');
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="col-md-4">Upload Foto</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="file" name="foto">
    </div>                
 </div>
```

**Error** [image: error]

Comment: Are you sending content type as multipart/form-data from frontend?

Comment: Share your full view code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check wheather you are getting file or not by `var_dump($request->file('foto')->getClientOriginalName());`

And make sure your form has `enctype="multipart/form-data"` set

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="{{ url('/store')}}">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="col-md-4">Upload Foto</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="file" name="foto">
    </div>                
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: its work, thank you sir. how to show image in my view. is it same in general.?

Comment: @NaKoriah glad to know :)

Comment: but, in my database. field created_at and update_at, is NULL.?

Comment: That's bcz u haven't set that in object array.

Comment: `'created_at' => $admin['created_at'],` `'updated_at' => $admin['updated_at'],`. like that.?

Comment: Yes but these days will not come in `$admin` however you can set it as this:



`'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), 'updated_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`

Answer (score 0):

Error because of client Side

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="{{ url('/store')}}">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="" class="col-md-4">Upload Foto</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="file" name="foto">
    </div>                
</div>
</form>
```

you ned to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` inside the form

If You are using the `form builder version`

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => ['store'],'autocomplete' => 'off','files' => 'true','enctype'=>'multipart/form-data' ]) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Then In your Controller You  can check if the request has the file

I have Created the **simple handy function** to upload the file

Open Your Controller And Paste the code below

```
private function uploadFile($fileName = '', $destinationPath = '')
    {
        $fileOriginalName = $fileName->getClientOriginalName();
        $timeStringFile = md5(time() . mt_rand(1, 10)) . $fileOriginalName;
        $fileName->move($destinationPath, $timeStringFile);
        return $timeStringFile;
    }
```

And the `store` method

`Eloquent` way

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $destinationPath    = public_path().'images/';

        $fotoFile='';

        if ($request->hasFile('foto'))
        {
            $fotoFile= $this->uploadFile($request->foto,$destinationPath    );
        }
        Admin::create(array_merge($request->all() , ['foto' => $fotoFile]));
        return redirect()->route('admin-index')->with('success','Admin Created Successfully');
    }
```

`DB` Facade Version

if You are using `DB` use  `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;`  `in top of your Controller`

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $admin              =  $request->all();    
        $destinationPath    = public_path().'images/';

        $fotoFile='';

        if ($request->hasFile('foto'))
        {
            $fotoFile = $this->uploadFile($request->foto,$destinationPath    );
        }

        $obj = array (
            'foto'  => $fotoFile,
            'nama_admin' => $admin['nama_admin'],
            'email' => $admin['email'],
            'jabatan' => $admin['jabatan'],
            'password' => $admin['password'],
            'confirm_password' => $admin['confirm_password']
        );

        DB::table('admins')->insert($obj);

        return redirect()->route('admin-index');
    }
```

Hope it is clear